# Off-heap memory grows without bound using streaming api

Tags: spring-boot, grpc-java

My grpc-java server off-heap memory grows without bound.

gRPC version

- server: grpc-java 1.34.1
- client: grpc-java 1.34.1, gRPC-Swift 1.0.0

Other information

- Server-side streaming RPC for chat service.
- Connection over SSL, SSL offload is processed on load balancer.
- Load is not so high

  - Under 100 RPCs/sec per server.
  - Under 10 RPCs/sec per client.
  - I didn't apply flow-control.
- Total client count is limited; it doesn't really differs that much between the time span.
- Server keepalive configurations

  - keepalive-time: 30s
  - keepalive-timeout: 5s
  - max-connection-idle: 60s
- Every 3:00 at night I perform onComplete() against all the `StreamObserver`s on the server; Chat service is not served this moment.
- Client randomly gets `INTERNAL: RST_STREAM closed stream. HTTP/2 error code: INTERNAL_ERROR` from LB, so I guess there'll be some broken connections left on server side.

  - I know this load balancer issue is unusual; It's under inspection.
- Mobile clients abruptly disconnect from server for various reasons and reconnect to server; I guess there'll be some broken connections left on server side here, too.

  - Possibly weird connection misuse on clients might exist; i.e. unexpected multiple connections with streams
- I get `io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError` once memory reaches limit. Memory is configured with below:

  - `-Xmx1536m`
  - `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=3584m`

Some observations

- Couldn't find memory leak with option below

  - `-Dio.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.leakDetection.level=PARANOID -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=PARANOID`
- Once the memory is grown it doesn't drop even after the 3:00 `onComplete()` event; I expect connection related resources will be freed after the connection being idle.
- There was one moment memory dropped, with below error; And I guess this triggered the memory release.

  - `io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$StreamException: Stream closed before write could take place`
- As I've tested,

  - After getting connected and the stream got open from the server-side, calling `onComplete()`, after the keepalive period server sends `OUTBOUND GO_AWAY`.

  ```
  2021-04-07T20:36:18.051+09:00 DEBUG 35024 --- [       grpc-nio-worker-ELG-3-4] [ i.g.n.s.i.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler: 214] : [id: 0x333386d4, L:/172.20.40.169:31105 - R:/172.20.40.169:50188] OUTBOUND GO_AWAY: lastStreamId=2147483647 errorCode=0 length=8 bytes=6d61785f69646c65
  2021-04-07T20:36:18.051+09:00 DEBUG 35024 --- [       grpc-nio-worker-ELG-3-4] [ i.g.n.s.i.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler: 214] : [id: 0x333386d4, L:/172.20.40.169:31105 - R:/172.20.40.169:50188] OUTBOUND PING: ack=false bytes=40715087873
  2021-04-07T20:36:18.060+09:00 DEBUG 35024 --- [       grpc-nio-worker-ELG-3-4] [ i.g.n.s.i.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler: 214] : [id: 0x333386d4, L:/172.20.40.169:31105 - R:/172.20.40.169:50188] INBOUND PING: ack=true bytes=40715087873
  2021-04-07T20:36:18.061+09:00 DEBUG 35024 --- [       grpc-nio-worker-ELG-3-4] [ i.g.n.s.i.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler: 214] : [id: 0x333386d4, L:/172.20.40.169:31105 - R:/172.20.40.169:50188] OUTBOUND GO_AWAY: lastStreamId=5 errorCode=0 length=8 bytes=6d61785f69646c65
  ```

  - However when I open the connection and stream then kill the process abruptly, server never sends `OUTBOUND GOAWAY`.

Here're my questions:

1. Is it sane not sending `OUTBOUND GO_AWAY` after abruptly killing the process? Do the resources get freed after the keepalive period or any other period of time?
2. What should be the reason memory getting not freed even the service is not in use and `StreamObserver`s all `onCompleted()`?
3. If it's all about unfreed broken connection resources, will `maxConnectionAge` with `maxConnectionAgeGrace` help this situation? With these options, I see `GO_AWAY` with normal connections however don't see any log with abruptly disconnected connections.
4. I expect unreferenced `StreamObserver` objects and related resources in direct memory to be garbage collected. Should I explicitly call `onCompleted()` or `onError()` for resource release?; I've actually calling `onError()` and `onCompleted()` on all `StreamObserver`s for termination however asking just in case.
5. Is there any chance this is caused from client's grpc library bug?

[Figure: Chat service was active between 4/3 12:00 and 16:30 and memory never freed. Chat service resumed at 4/4 16:00. Memory growth trend looks like exponential.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uceae.png)

I'm sorry not providing any source code here, if you need a reproducible source I'll get it ready; the original source is on production so I can't provide it this moment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have responded to your query on grpc-java at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/8058

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue with `INTERNAL: RST_STREAM closed stream. HTTP/2 error code: INTERNAL_ERROR`? We've seen this in the wild for clients interacting with our service and haven't been able to find much on the topic.